# CSV File With PHP and MySQL - Data not uploading properly in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I download the script from - http://www.k-fez.com/?p=101 website and trying to upload CSV file on my server. It uploading file successfully but Blank - please check image

```
<?PHP
session_start();

if($_FILES["file"]["type"] != "application/vnd.ms-excel"){
    die("This is not a CSV file.");
}
elseif(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
    //Connect to the database
    $dbhost = 'Localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'password';
    $dbname = 'auction_tbl';
    $link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql server');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    //Process the CSV file
    $findings = "
<form method=\"post\" action=\"importCSV.php\">
<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">
  <tr>
<td>Checking...</td>
";
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";"); //Remove if CSV file does not have column headings
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
$auction_id = mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]);
$owner_id = mysql_real_escape_string($data[3]);
$list_in = mysql_real_escape_string($data[4]);
$auction_type = mysql_real_escape_string($data[5]);
$start_time = mysql_real_escape_string($data[6]);
$start_time_type = mysql_real_escape_string($data[7]);
$end_time = mysql_real_escape_string($data[8]);
$end_time_type = mysql_real_escape_string($data[9]);
$duration = mysql_real_escape_string($data[10]);
$quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($data[11]);
$category_id = mysql_real_escape_string($data[12]);
$addl_category_id = mysql_real_escape_string($data[13]);
$currency = mysql_real_escape_string($data[14]);
$start_price = mysql_real_escape_string($data[15]);
$reserve_price = mysql_real_escape_string($data[16]);
$buyout_price = mysql_real_escape_string($data[17]);
$is_offer = mysql_real_escape_string($data[18]);
$offer_min = mysql_real_escape_string($data[19]);
$offer_max = mysql_real_escape_string($data[20]);
$enable_swap = mysql_real_escape_string($data[21]);
$bid_increment_amount = mysql_real_escape_string($data[22]);
$zip_code = mysql_real_escape_string($data[23]);
$state = mysql_real_escape_string($data[24]);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($data[25]);
$postage_amount = mysql_real_escape_string($data[26]);
$insurance_amount = mysql_real_escape_string($data[27]);
$item_weight = mysql_real_escape_string($data[28]);
$shipping_method = mysql_real_escape_string($data[29]);
$shipping_int = mysql_real_escape_string($data[30]);
$type_service = mysql_real_escape_string($data[31]);
$shipping_details = mysql_real_escape_string($data[32]);
$payment_methods = mysql_real_escape_string($data[33]);
$direct_payment = mysql_real_escape_string($data[34]);
$hpfeat = mysql_real_escape_string($data[35]);
$catfeat = mysql_real_escape_string($data[36]);
$bold = mysql_real_escape_string($data[37]);
$hl = mysql_real_escape_string($data[38]);
$hidden_bidding = mysql_real_escape_string($data[39]);
$apply_tax = mysql_real_escape_string($data[40]);
$auto_relist_bids = mysql_real_escape_string($data[41]);
$auto_relist_nb = mysql_real_escape_string($data[42]);
$force_payment = mysql_real_escape_string($data[43]);
$fb_decrement_amount = mysql_real_escape_string($data[44]);
$fb_decrement_interval = mysql_real_escape_string($data[45]);
$fb_next_decrement = mysql_real_escape_string($data[46]);
$images_details = mysql_real_escape_string($data[47]);
$media_details = mysql_real_escape_string($data[48]);
$dd_details = mysql_real_escape_string($data[49]);
$custom_fields_details = mysql_real_escape_string($data[50]);
$import_date = mysql_real_escape_string($data[51]);

        //Check if row is in database already
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM `bulk_listings`
                WHERE `auction_id` = '" . $auction_id . "'";    //In this example attribute0 is the primary key
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count > 0){
            $findings = $findings . "
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor=\"#FF0000\">DB Duplicate</td>
<td>" . $auction_id . "</td>
<td>" . $name . "</td>
<td>" . $description . "</td>
<td>" . $owner_id . "</td>
<td>" . $list_in . "</td>
<td>" . $auction_type . "</td>
<td>" . $start_time . "</td>
<td>" . $start_time_type . "</td>
<td>" . $end_time . "</td>
<td>" . $end_time_type . "</td>
<td>" . $duration . "</td>
<td>" . $quantity . "</td>
<td>" . $category_id . "</td>
<td>" . $addl_category_id . "</td>
<td>" . $currency . "</td>
<td>" . $start_price . "</td>
<td>" . $reserve_price . "</td>
<td>" . $buyout_price . "</td>
<td>" . $is_offer . "</td>
<td>" . $offer_min . "</td>
<td>" . $offer_max . "</td>
<td>" . $enable_swap . "</td>
<td>" . $bid_increment_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $zip_code . "</td>
<td>" . $state . "</td>
<td>" . $country . "</td>
<td>" . $postage_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $insurance_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $item_weight . "</td>
<td>" . $shipping_method . "</td>
<td>" . $shipping_int . "</td>
<td>" . $type_service . "</td>
<td>" . $shipping_details . "</td>
<td>" . $payment_methods . "</td>
<td>" . $direct_payment . "</td>
<td>" . $hpfeat . "</td>
<td>" . $catfeat . "</td>
<td>" . $bold . "</td>
<td>" . $hl . "</td>
<td>" . $hidden_bidding . "</td>
<td>" . $apply_tax . "</td>
<td>" . $auto_relist_bids . "</td>
<td>" . $auto_relist_nb . "</td>
<td>" . $force_payment . "</td>
<td>" . $fb_decrement_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $fb_decrement_interval . "</td>
<td>" . $fb_next_decrement . "</td>
<td>" . $images_details . "</td>
<td>" . $media_details . "</td>
<td>" . $dd_details . "</td>
<td>" . $custom_fields_details . "</td>
<td>" . $import_date . "</td>
  </tr>";
        }

        //Check if row is already in INSERT queue
        elseif(strpos($_SESSION['insert'], "'" . $auction_id . "'") != false){
            $findings = $findings . "
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor=\"#FF0000\">File Duplicate</td>
<td>" . $auction_id . "</td>
<td>" . $name . "</td>
<td>" . $description . "</td>
<td>" . $owner_id . "</td>
<td>" . $list_in . "</td>
<td>" . $auction_type . "</td>
<td>" . $start_time . "</td>
<td>" . $start_time_type . "</td>
<td>" . $end_time . "</td>
<td>" . $end_time_type . "</td>
<td>" . $duration . "</td>
<td>" . $quantity . "</td>
<td>" . $category_id . "</td>
<td>" . $addl_category_id . "</td>
<td>" . $currency . "</td>
<td>" . $start_price . "</td>
<td>" . $reserve_price . "</td>
<td>" . $buyout_price . "</td>
<td>" . $is_offer . "</td>
<td>" . $offer_min . "</td>
<td>" . $offer_max . "</td>
<td>" . $enable_swap . "</td>
<td>" . $bid_increment_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $zip_code . "</td>
<td>" . $state . "</td>
<td>" . $country . "</td>
<td>" . $postage_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $insurance_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $item_weight . "</td>
<td>" . $shipping_method . "</td>
<td>" . $shipping_int . "</td>
<td>" . $type_service . "</td>
<td>" . $shipping_details . "</td>
<td>" . $payment_methods . "</td>
<td>" . $direct_payment . "</td>
<td>" . $hpfeat . "</td>
<td>" . $catfeat . "</td>
<td>" . $bold . "</td>
<td>" . $hl . "</td>
<td>" . $hidden_bidding . "</td>
<td>" . $apply_tax . "</td>
<td>" . $auto_relist_bids . "</td>
<td>" . $auto_relist_nb . "</td>
<td>" . $force_payment . "</td>
<td>" . $fb_decrement_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $fb_decrement_interval . "</td>
<td>" . $fb_next_decrement . "</td>
<td>" . $images_details . "</td>
<td>" . $media_details . "</td>
<td>" . $dd_details . "</td>
<td>" . $custom_fields_details . "</td>
<td>" . $import_date . "</td>
  </tr>";
        }

        //Row is unique
        else{
            //Add INSERT statement to INSERT queue
            $_SESSION['insert'] .= "INSERT INTO `bulk_listings` (
        `auction_id`,
        `name`,
        `description`,
        `owner_id`,
        `list_in`,
        `auction_type`,
        `start_time`,
        `start_time_type`,
        `end_time`,
        `end_time_type`,
        `duration`,
        `quantity`,
        `category_id`,
        `addl_category_id`,
        `currency`,
        `start_price`,
        `reserve_price`,
        `buyout_price`,
        `is_offer`,
        `offer_min`,
        `offer_max`,
        `enable_swap`,
        `bid_increment_amount`,
        `zip_code`,
        `state`,
        `country`,
        `postage_amount`,
        `insurance_amount`,
        `item_weight`,
        `shipping_method`,
        `shipping_int`,
        `type_service`,
        `shipping_details`,
        `payment_methods`,
        `direct_payment`,
        `hpfeat`,
        `catfeat`,
        `bold`,
        `hl`,
        `hidden_bidding`,
        `apply_tax`,
        `auto_relist_bids`,
        `auto_relist_nb`,
        `force_payment`,
        `fb_decrement_amount`,
        `fb_decrement_interval`,
        `fb_next_decrement`,
        `images_details`,
        `media_details`,
        `dd_details`,
        `custom_fields_details`,
        `import_date`
                    )
                    VALUES ('" . $auction_id . "', '" . $name . "', '" . $description . "', '" . $owner_id . "', '" . $list_in . "', '" . $auction_type . "', '" . $start_time . "', '" . $start_time_type . "', '" . $end_time . "', '" . $end_time_type . "', '" . $duration . "', '" . $quantity . "', '" . $category_id . "', '" . $addl_category_id . "', '" . $currency . "', '" . $start_price . "', '" . $reserve_price . "', '" . $buyout_price . "', '" . $is_offer . "', '" . $offer_min . "', '" . $offer_max . "', '" . $enable_swap . "', '" . $bid_increment_amount . "', '" . $zip_code . "', '" . $state . "', '" . $country . "', '" . $postage_amount . "', '" . $insurance_amount . "', '" . $item_weight . "', '" . $shipping_method . "', '" . $shipping_int . "', '" . $type_service . "', '" . $shipping_details . "', '" . $payment_methods . "', '" . $direct_payment . "', '" . $hpfeat . "', '" . $catfeat . "', '" . $bold . "', '" . $hl . "', '" . $hidden_bidding . "', '" . $apply_tax . "', '" . $auto_relist_bids . "', '" . $auto_relist_nb . "', '" . $force_payment . "', '" . $fb_decrement_amount . "', '" . $fb_decrement_interval . "', '" . $fb_next_decrement . "', '" . $images_details . "', '" . $media_details . "', '" . $dd_details . "', '" . $custom_fields_details . "', '" . $import_date . "');";

            //Add row for row to findings table and mark unique
            $findings = $findings . "
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor=\"#00FF00\">&nbsp;</td>
<td>" . $auction_id . "</td>
<td>" . $name . "</td>
<td>" . $description . "</td>
<td>" . $owner_id . "</td>
<td>" . $list_in . "</td>
<td>" . $auction_type . "</td>
<td>" . $start_time . "</td>
<td>" . $start_time_type . "</td>
<td>" . $end_time . "</td>
<td>" . $end_time_type . "</td>
<td>" . $duration . "</td>
<td>" . $quantity . "</td>
<td>" . $category_id . "</td>
<td>" . $addl_category_id . "</td>
<td>" . $currency . "</td>
<td>" . $start_price . "</td>
<td>" . $reserve_price . "</td>
<td>" . $buyout_price . "</td>
<td>" . $is_offer . "</td>
<td>" . $offer_min . "</td>
<td>" . $offer_max . "</td>
<td>" . $enable_swap . "</td>
<td>" . $bid_increment_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $zip_code . "</td>
<td>" . $state . "</td>
<td>" . $country . "</td>
<td>" . $postage_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $insurance_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $item_weight . "</td>
<td>" . $shipping_method . "</td>
<td>" . $shipping_int . "</td>
<td>" . $type_service . "</td>
<td>" . $shipping_details . "</td>
<td>" . $payment_methods . "</td>
<td>" . $direct_payment . "</td>
<td>" . $hpfeat . "</td>
<td>" . $catfeat . "</td>
<td>" . $bold . "</td>
<td>" . $hl . "</td>
<td>" . $hidden_bidding . "</td>
<td>" . $apply_tax . "</td>
<td>" . $auto_relist_bids . "</td>
<td>" . $auto_relist_nb . "</td>
<td>" . $force_payment . "</td>
<td>" . $fb_decrement_amount . "</td>
<td>" . $fb_decrement_interval . "</td>
<td>" . $fb_next_decrement . "</td>
<td>" . $images_details . "</td>
<td>" . $media_details . "</td>
<td>" . $dd_details . "</td>
<td>" . $custom_fields_details . "</td>
<td>" . $import_date . "</td>
  </tr>";
        }
    }
    mysql_close($link);

    $findings = $findings . "
  <tr>
    <td colspan=\"5\"><div align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Confirm\" /></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>";
    echo $findings;
}
else{
    die("You shouldn't be here");
}
?>
```

importCSV.php (Sorry i forgot to not another file code.)

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['insert'])){
    die("You shouldn't be here.");
}

//Connect to the database
    $dbhost = 'Localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'password';
    $dbname = 'auction_tbl';
    $link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql server');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

$queries = explode(';', $_SESSION['insert']);

foreach($queries as $query){
    if($query != ""){
        mysql_query($query);
    }
}

mysql_close($link);

echo "Done";
?>
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: There is a way to do this in a quarter of the code.  For a start you should map all your data to the variable names in the order they are displayed and then loop through them and build the rows.  Do the same when building the INSERT statement.

Comment: You should use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting data to a web page to prevent XSS. You shouldn't output escaped strings (using `mysql_real_escape_string`) to a web page. BTW, your code is hard to read due to improper indenting.

Comment: The script appends the `INSERT` statement to the variable `$insert`, but never calls `mysql_query()` on it. I don't see how you're getting any data loaded at all. You also can't put multiple statements in a call to `mysql_query()`, so I don't understand why you're using this queue. If you want bulk insert, you should use a single `INSERT` statement with multiple `VALUES` lists.

Comment: I update the post. I tried with htmlspecialchars but it still not working

Comment: in importCSV.php echo your `$query` and check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

```
//loop through the csv file and insert into database
do {
    if ($data[0]) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts_tmp (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                '".addslashes($data[2])."'
            )
        ");
    }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Database Field Data type Properly ..
I think database field data type is wrong for this problem..