# Remove the first row from CSV file - php csv file upload issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This script running fine but adding first row from excel file (header names). I want to make ignore first row in loop - Please check the script -

```
<?php

//connect to the database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
mysql_select_db("mydatadb",$connect); //select the table
//

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");
    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO bulk_listings (name, description, owner_id, list_in, auction_type, start_time, start_time_type, end_time, end_time_type, duration, quantity, category_id, addl_category_id, currency, start_price, reserve_price, buyout_price, is_offer, offer_min, offer_max) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[10])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[11])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[12])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[13])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[14])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[15])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[16])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[17])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[18])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[19])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[20])."'
                )
            ");
        }
    }
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,10000,",")); 
    //redirect
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die;
}
?>
```

Another file called Import.php

```
<?php

//connect to the database

mysql_connect ("localhost","root","password")
  or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());

echo "connected to database!";

mysql_select_db ("mydatadb");

// Insert data into table

        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]);
        $description = mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]);
        $owner_id = mysql_real_escape_string($data[3]);
        $list_in = mysql_real_escape_string($data[4]);
        $auction_type = mysql_real_escape_string($data[5]);
        $start_time = mysql_real_escape_string($data[6]);
        $start_time_type = mysql_real_escape_string($data[7]);
        $end_time = mysql_real_escape_string($data[8]);
        $end_time_type = mysql_real_escape_string($data[9]);
        $duration = mysql_real_escape_string($data[10]);
        $quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($data[11]);
        $category_id = mysql_real_escape_string($data[12]);
        $addl_category_id = mysql_real_escape_string($data[13]);
        $currency = mysql_real_escape_string($data[14]);
        $start_price = mysql_real_escape_string($data[15]);
        $reserve_price = mysql_real_escape_string($data[16]);
        $buyout_price = mysql_real_escape_string($data[17]);
        $is_offer = mysql_real_escape_string($data[18]);
        $offer_min = mysql_real_escape_string($data[19]);
        $offer_max = mysql_real_escape_string($data[20]);

$action = mysql_real_escape_string('insert php code for button here');

$query = "INSERT INTO bulk_listings
         (name, description, owner_id, list_in, auction_type, start_time, start_time_type, end_time, end_time_type, duration, quantity, category_id, addl_category_id, currency, start_price, reserve_price, buyout_price, is_offer, offer_min, offer_max)
         VALUES
         ('$name', '$description', '$owner_id', '$list_in', '$auction_type', '$start_time', '$start_time_type', '$end_time', '$end_time_type', '$duration', '$quantity', '$category_id', '$addl_category_id', '$currency', '$start_price', '$reserve_price', '$buyout_price', '$is_offer', '$offer_min', '$offer_max') ";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');

echo "Database updated successfully!";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried with - fgetcsv() & while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,10000,","));  But still not working.

Please help me and tell where i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: reverse your do/while and make it a simple while loop; otherwise the first $data row is only fetched __after__ executing the code within the loop

Comment: And learn how to use MySQLi with prepared statements, when you're mass inserting like this, a prepared statement can boost performance

Comment: may I also suggest (if your cant use mysqli) looking at `array_map()` and `implode()` to reduce your code down some. ie array_map $data with mysql_real_escape_string, and `$data_values="'".implode("','", $data)."'";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first part of the posted code you need to add a line after you create the handle, so line:

```
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
```

becomes:

```
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
fgetcsv($handle,10000,",");
```

This will get the first line and then ignore it in the loop because the pointer will be in the second line when the loop starts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. now it address properly all column but it inserting a blank row. is there any changes in - while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,10000,","));

Comment: If you want to ignore all empty columns,
change:

if ($data[0]) {

to:

if (!empty($data[0])) {

Comment: Thanks for reply. Still same problem - Please check the image - http://oi39.tinypic.com/53wksy.jpg

Comment: Can you provide an example of the csv data file?

Comment: Also I see that at the end of the import you redirect to the second file and try to insert again there. In the second file tho, the $data is undefined and has no information inside, this means that all variables will be null, hence the empty line. I suggest you remove all php from the second file and just keep the message: 
echo "Database updated successfully!";

Comment: You can see there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444676/csv-file-with-php-and-mysql-data-not-uploading-properly-in-database#comment23586687_16444676

Comment: OK try removing the code from the second file (see previous comment) and give some feedback please.

Comment: What the stupid I am ... You are right Thanpa, I remove the php script from 2nd file and its working fine now... Thank you very much

Comment: what a bad suggestion. reverse the looping conditions instead. If it's a pre-condition, it belongs to the top. In any case, the question on it's own is of very low quality so probably there is not much that an answer can be helpful, so I partially blame the question with the DV as well.

Answer (score 0):

you basically want to remove the first index from the array which is your first row..

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle,10000,","));
$data = array_shift($data);
```

Comment: I used your script also in my 1st file and learn about this script... Thank you very much for your help.